# Azure Data Factory with Managed private endpoints is failed to connect

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am configuring the  Azure Data Factory that reads the data from the storage account and updates the Azure SQL Server.

I have created the Managed private endpoints(**manually**) for both Storage account & Azure SQL server

[image]

**Managed private endpoints:**

[image]

**Enabled Interactive Authoring:**

[image]

and disabled the Public network access on both the Storage account and Azure SQL server.

[image]

But, it is failing to connect with the Storage account and Azure SQL server

**Azure SQL Server Connection:**

[image]

**Storage Account Connection:**

[image]

**Failed to Connect - Storage Account#: 9972**

[image]

**Failed to Connect - SQL Server#: 22339**

[image]

**Update#1** As suggested in comment, I have associated the linked services with IR

[image]

[image]

It seems to be Connecting

[image]

But, Pipeline works only when I allow

[image]

Otherwise, it fails with

[image]

The service Principal has permission on the Storage account

[image]

**Permissions:**

[image]

Comment: What is the error message

Comment: Are the Linked Services connected to IntegrationRuntime1?  If not, change them and try again.  You can verify the connection in the Linked Service itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this with the following Terraform Code

```
// Create Private Endpoint for Data Factory Portal
module "pedatafactoryportal" {
    source = "./modules/privateendpoint/"

    resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.resource_group.name
    location = azurerm_resource_group.resource_group.location
    name = var.privateendpointdatafactory_portal_name

    subnet_id = azurerm_subnet.endpoint_subnet.id
    private_link_enabled_resource_id = azurerm_data_factory.datafactory.id
    private_dns_zone_name = azurerm_private_dns_zone.datafactoryportalzone.name
    subresource_names = ["portal"]
    resource_name = "portal"

    depends_on = [
      azurerm_data_factory.datafactory, 
      azurerm_private_dns_zone.datafactoryportalzone
    ]
}
```